# How do I combine all of my Azure Application Insights objects into a single report?

Tags: azure, reporting, azure-application-insights

I use a application insights for each app but I want to create a report in PowerBI that for example shows me all the exceptions for the day from all of the Application Insights.

A workaround is just have all the apps start to use a single Application Insight but I would rather not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no "out of the box" way to achieve that. We are working on enabling cross-ikey queries in analytics that will enable this in a very simple way - please cast your vote for this here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/15165558-support-for-cross-ikey-queries

The current workaround for this is to export the data using continuous export, and load the data into some store (like SQL) and use a reporting on top of it. See some example here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-code-sample-export-sql-stream-analytics/

Comment: Its just me doing everything so Ill just combine them and prefix the names with the project name. Much easier